# Software for task management of a coop?

Tags: project-management, todo

I live in a 26 person housing cooperative! We are self-governed, cooperatively owned and share duties of the house. I have been appointed to streamline the process of task management and I am currently looking for software to help us automate our current system of task management.

Features we would need:

- Users should be reminded when a task is due
- Admin should be notified when a user does not complete a task We have a system whereby when people fail to do their jobs, they get strikes and those strikes can sometimes lead to extra "penance" jobs.
- It would be great if a user could have a counter which aggregated
  automatically when they don't complete a task, which I can override
  if we reach an agreement.

There are basically two kinds of tasks we need:

- The first is specific to a user's role within the house which must be done by the same person, once a week, every week. Things like "Food buyer" and "Basement cleaner" etc. These have subtasks; I will want written reports in some cases, but mostly boxes to check.
- The second kind of task is more like a work "shift." Things like washing dishes, cooking dinner and cleaning the bathrooms. Everyone has to sign up for a fixed number of shifts every "cycle". These will have subtasks which are checkboxes.

Other preferences:

- Money is definitely a concern for us. It would be great to find something which is free, and even better to find something which is open source/extensible.
- Simple; some of the people in the coop are older generation and would have a hard time with something that has a lot of jargon.
- Mobile friendly; most people will want to read and check off tasks while they're doing them and won't be in front of a computer. Doesn't have to necessarily have an cross-platform app, although that would be nice.

I'm a full-stack web-developer, and I could probably develop something like this, but it would be time consuming and I would rather not reinvent the wheel if something like this already exists. However, if something is open source and pretty close to our needs, I could probably work from the API or modify it slightly to be a full solution.

Comment: I don’t know of any & won’t bother to Google, since you can do that :-) But, off the  top of my head, I would think that a CMS, such as Drupal, would have plugins for task management.  OK, a very quick Google then. How’s about https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/moshnoi/2637294 ? I am certain that Drupal will handle it, but the go- to place for all things CMS is http://cmsmatrix.org/ where you will be sure to to find something. CMS means browser based, which you seem to want. Let us know if you find something.

Comment: Jeez, thanks! 

I hadn't even thought about using a CMS system, though I've used them before. This might actually be exactly what we need :)

Comment: it helps to have a rubber duck :-) Don't forget to post an answer, when you find something, to help others in future.

Comment: I think Asana would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quire](https://quire.io) is very, very good. But the free version is limited to 10 members.

As to the specific needs:

- Users should be reminded when a task is due: Yes. configurable notifications available.
- Admin should be notified when a user does not complete a task: Yes. Overdue task factor in the standard notifications list.
- Counter which aggregated automatically when they don't complete a task: Myabe. Custom fields are now available that allow scripting.
- Once a week, every week tasks: Yes
- Subtasks: Yes
- Boxes to check: Yes
- Everyone has to sign up for a fixed number of shifts: No.
- Money: Free one is limited to 10 members.
- Simple: Not really. It would take some getting used to.
- Mobile friendly: Yes. Apps are good.

Pricing and features list available [here](https://quire.io/pricing).

(Note: I am not affiliated with Quire in any way.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if it meets all your requirements but I actually find Jira to be a great way to manage any kind of ongoing delegated tasks and checking in for completion.

Comment: I thonk the idea is to give more details or your experience of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).